# Set default nested state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two level nested state on ui-router and I can't set a default nested state for some view.

I need to load the state `cars.detail.supply.list` when the state `cars.detail` is active without changing the current url.

I'm expecting to show `supplies` list without click on `List supplies` button.

What am I missing?

**Full code:** https://plnkr.co/edit/DqwhaDXh3biMbq9PLCV3?p=preview

### ui-states:

```
.state('cars.detail', {
    parent: 'cars',
    url: '/edit/:id',
    views: {
        'content@index': {
            templateUrl: 'cars.detail.html',
            controller: 'CarDetailController'
        },
        'supplies': {
            templateUrl: 'cars.supply.html',
            controller: 'CarDetailController'
        }
    }
})

.state('cars.detail.supply', {
    url: '',
    parent: 'cars.detail',
    abstract: true,
    //'default': '.list',
    views: {
        'supplies@cars.detail': {
            templateUrl: 'cars.supply.html',
            //controller: 'SupplyListController'
        }
    }
})
.state('cars.detail.supply.list', {
    parent: 'cars.detail.supply',
    url: '',
    views: {
        '@cars.detail.supply': {
            templateUrl: 'cars.supply.list.html',
            controller: 'SupplyListController'
        }
    }
})
.state('cars.detail.supply.add', {
    parent: 'cars.detail.supply',
    url: '/add-supply',
    views: {
        '@cars.detail.supply': {
            templateUrl: 'cars.supply.add.html',
            controller: 'AddSupplyController'
        }
    }    
})
```

### The view:

```
<div>
    ...

    <h4 ng-if="car.id">
        Supplies

        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ui-sref="cars.detail.supply.add({ carId: car.id })">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add supply
        </a>

        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ui-sref="cars.detail.supply.list({ carId: car.id })">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> List supplies
        </a>
    </h4>
    <div ui-view="supplies" class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**I've tried:**

- https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-default
- set abstract state for `cars.detail.supply`
- solutions from many SO related questions
- set `url = ''` as mentioned here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it to work, you have to differentiate the `cars.detail`'s and `cars.detail.supply.list`'s urls. So, step one is to give `cars.detail.supply.list` a url:

```
.state('cars.detail.supply.list', {
    parent: 'cars.detail.supply',
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'cars.supply.list.html',
    controller: 'SupplyListController'
})
```

Once the state urls can be differentiated, you need to transition to the list state by either updating the link in the car list repeater to

```
ui-sref="cars.detail.supply.list(...)"
```

or

by indicating a redirect from the `details` state to the details's `list` state in `app.js`:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/dashboard/cars/edit/{id}', '/dashboard/cars/edit/{id}/list');
```

Comment: On my `dashboard` state I'm able to show `cars.list.html` by default. Why I can do the same inside `car.detail`?